# Adding dataset to ArcMap with ArcObjects and C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am trying to add feature dataset to ArcMap as a layer

I  tried some code but addlayer needs iLayer but IFeatureDataset can't casting as ilayer

How Add dataset to ArcMap?

```
       ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as
                                               ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new 
                    ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory();
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS\TemplateData.gdb", ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureDataset fd = fws.OpenFeatureDataset("World");
```

Comment: Please do not repost questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a FeatureDataset with a FeatureClass. A FeatureDataset is a collection of (related) FeatureClasses grouped together. A FeatureClass is a single table containing a geometry field.

It is not possible to add a FeatureDataset as a layer to the map.

To add a FeatureClass to the map, you need to create a FeatureLayer object, and assign it's FeatureClass property. The FeatureLayer can be added to the map.

```
var fl = new FeatureLayerClass();
fl.FeatureClass = fws.OpenFeatureClass(...);
map.AddLayer(fl);
((IActiveView)map).Refresh();
```

Comment: Yes FeatureDataset is a collection of FeatureClasses but when added FeatureClass to the map its add only single featureclass.  what i do add all featureclass in a featuredata set.

Comment: Use the `Subsets` property, or the `IFeatureClassContainer` interface of the feature dataset to loop over all contained featureclasses and add those one by one.